# Screenshot to any screen with button on top

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

I have a button on top, that allows me to explore my android ui, and I'm trying to add a screenshot action to it , and the part of adding an action to the button works just fine, what doesn't work is the screenshot code, but this code works when i add this code to an `"myactivity"` button, but when i'm exploring the android ui, and when this action is on my allways on top button, it gives me a black image with no data (0 kb). this is my screenshot code:

```
View content = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
   File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.png");
   try 
   {
       file.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
       ostream.close();
   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

maybe the problem is the `content`or 
maybe this can't be done without root access, but if root access
 is needed, can you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code for taking a screen shot via a shell command on rooted device
'fileDestination' is the path for the location at which you want your screenshot file to be saved.

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

        OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + fileDestination).getBytes("ASCII"));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,LOG_LABEL+" IOException e:: SCREENSHOT FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,LOG_LABEL+"InterruptedException e:: SCREENSHOT FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```